# Ошибка при копировании строк файла

Tags: delphi, файлы, pascal, pascalabc.net, копирование

Написал программу, осуществляющую копирование строк из файла

```
var
f1, f2: text;
s: string;
num1, num2, count : integer;
begin
write('Input num1=');
readln(num1);
write('Input num2=');
readln(num2);
count:=0;
assign (f1, 'd:\my.txt');
reset (f1);

assign (f2, 'd:\mynew.txt');
rewrite (f2);

while not eof (f1) do begin
    count:=count+1;
    readln (f1, s);
    if ((count>=num1) and (count<=num2)) then
    writeln (f2, s);
end;

close (f1);
close (f2);
end.
```

Опробывал на `.txt` файлах - не получилось: файл `d:\mynew.txt` пустой.

Comment: Не понял проблемы, что сделать там надо? Строку с каким-то номером считать из одного файла и заменить ей что-то в другом файле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Delphi сработало:

```
var
  f1, f2: textfile;
  s: string;
  num1, num2, count: Integer;
begin
  num1 := 3;
  num2 := 7;
  count := 0;
  assignfile(f1, 'f:\contact.vcf');
  reset(f1);

  assignfile(f2, 'f:\mynew.txt');
  rewrite(f2);
  while not eof(f1) do
  begin
    count := count + 1;
    readln(f1, s);
    if ((count >= num1) and (count <= num2)) then
      writeln(f2, s);
  end;

  closefile(f1);
  closefile(f2);
```

Кроме того, разумно было бы остановить чтение по достижению `num2`

```
 while (not eof(f1)) and (count < num2) do
 begin
    count := count + 1;
    readln(f1, s);
    if count >= num1 then
       writeln(f2, s);
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант для PascalABC.Net

```pascal
// PascalABC.Net 3.7.1

const
    OutFilename = 'out.txt'; 
    InFilename = 'in.txt';

begin
    //    var outfile := OpenWrite(OutFilename);
    //    for var i := 1 to 100 do
    //        outfile.WriteLn('Строка №', i);
    //    outfile.Close();
    //    exit;
    
    var num1 := ReadInteger('Input num1 = ');
    var num2 := ReadInteger('Input num2 = ');
    var outfile := OpenRead(OutFilename);
    var infile := OpenWrite(InFilename);
    
    var count := 0;
    while not outfile.Eof() do
    begin
        count += 1;
        var s := outfile.ReadlnString;
        if count > num2 then break;
        if count >= num1 then infile.WriteLn(s);
    end;
    
    outfile.Close();
    infile.Close();
end.
```